# Returning empty string from C++ through JNI to Java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm making a X-platform library and I'm trying to export it to Java.

There's a function which returns me a string:

**C++ code**

```
string results = "";


for (vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < resultsDouble.size(); i++) {
    for (it_type3 it = distances.begin(); it != distances.end(); ++it) {
        String key = it->first;
        double value = distances.at(key);

        if (value == resultsDouble.at(i)) {
            typesString.push_back(key);
            results = results + " " + key;
        }
    }
}

char const* resultsChar = results.c_str();

return resultsChar;
```

when printing it on Java, even on the JNI call it's empty.

It is empty as well if I make `to_string(results).c_str();`

But I know that the string isn't empty because when I print `to_string(results.length()).c_str();` it shows me 435 .

Why is it showing me an empty string?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

If I change my result to string, I get:

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 17339 (w.opencvtesting)

**EDIT 2**
I'm trying to to this:

```
string getMyString(string JSON, long proof) {
    string result = "";
    return result;
}
```

and what the log prints me is:

> Ж)¤

Comment: You should create a jstring object and return this from the jni call.

Comment: I debug printing the result (const char* type) and I send it via jstring as `jstring result = (env)->NewStringUTF(matchingString);`

Answer (score 2):

Your C++ code seems to be incorrect, because you return a pointer to data of a local `string results`, which is destroyed when the function exits. You should change it to:

```
string getMyString(...) {
    string results = "";
    ...
    return results;
}
```

Then convert is to `jstring` like you do:

```
jstring Java_com_MyFunc(JNIEnv* env, ...) {
    string result = getMyString(...);
    return env->NewStringUTF(result.c_str());
}
```

Comment: got > Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 17339 (w.opencvtesting)

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a `char const*` which points into a local
variable, which will be destructed when you leave the function.
You should return an `std::string`, which the JNI wrapper
converts directly to a `jstring`.

Comment: got > Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 17339 (w.opencvtesting)